# Distance to object, taking into account size of object

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

I have a number of polygon features on the edge of a lake feature. I also have sample points throughout the lake feature. I am looking to add some sort of indicator for these points as to how influences they are by a nearby wetland. For example, being 100m away from a large wetland should give a different value compared to 100m from a small wetland. In addition, 100m away from two small wetlands should give the same as being 100m away from a single 2x as large wetland.

Is there a single tool for this or do I need to do a calculation on my own. E.g. find distance, find size of nearest wetland and multiply.

Thinking maybe to write a program that takes distW1 * areaW1 + distW2 * areaW2 etc...

Comment: Do you need the distance from each sample point to each wetland or just the distance to the closest wetland?

Comment: The idea is to provide a measure of how accessible a particular point is to get to from a wetland. In a perfect world I would be able to take into account the closest wetland as well as the next closest etc. Do you think this is too difficult?

Comment: What is the chance once of your points is _exactly_ 100m from 2 wetland polygons? If you have an advance license have a look at the Generate Near Table tool and the parameter options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you are trying to plot the relationship between size of wetland and distance to your sample points. I don't think there is a single tool that will do what you want in one step. The Near tool in the Proximity toolset will calculate the closest distance to the other feature. The point distance tool will calculate the distance of every point in a feature class to every point in another. As far as I know there is not an equivalent tool that takes a polygon feature as input.